# Firebase modules import - SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

Tags: javascript, firebase, visual-studio-code

Hello friends and foes!

I've been desperately trying to set up a javascript web project using firebase and I can't seem to get over the first step: Properly importing the necessary "packages" for my project.

So far I have followed this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
meticulously, using the "modules bundles" option, but with no success.

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the Live Server extension to run my code on Google Chrome.

If nothing goes wrong, my browser should show the value in my database's "text" child.

Here's my code:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/database";

var firebaseConfig = { 
  apiKey: My Key,
  authDomain: My Domain,
  databaseURL: My URL,
  projectId: My Project,
  storageBucket: The Store Bucket,
  messagingSenderId: ID,
  appId: app ID
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const bigOne = document.getElementById('bigOne');

const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('text');

dbRefObject.on('value', snap => bigOne.innerText = snap.val());
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="bigOne"></h1>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="firebase_test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Easy breezy lemon squeezy I thought, but this is my output in the app's console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

I've tried using the CDN and hosting URL methods too, but virtual studio code didn't recognize those what so ever.

Thank you for your time and help, I appreciate it highly!

Greetings,
Raul

Comment: And what browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome! Sorry - I've edited my post accordingly.